# Need help in a C# code

Tags: c#

Can anybody explain me:

```
int Form1.SendMessage(int hwnd, int wMsg,int wParam, object IParam)
```

It is used to copy image to clipboard.

EXAMPLE:

```
SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY, 0, 0);
```

Here what are those parameters(`hwnd`,`wMsg`,`wParam`,`IParam`) mean?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206221/explanation-of-sendmessage-message-numbers).  Also, looking it up in the MSDN is a good place to start for explanations.

Answer (score 6):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx

**hWnd** - A handle to the window whose window procedure will receive the message. If this parameter is HWND_BROADCAST ((HWND)0xffff), the message is sent to all top-level windows in the system, including disabled or invisible unowned windows, overlapped windows, and pop-up windows; but the message is not sent to child windows.
Message sending is subject to UIPI. The thread of a process can send messages only to message queues of threads in processes of lesser or equal integrity level.

**Msg** - The message to be sent.
For lists of the system-provided messages, see System-Defined Messages.

**wParam** - Additional message-specific information.

**lParam** - Additional message-specific information.

**More info for using SendMessage in C#: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage**

Comment: Beat me by several seconds. +1.